# C++ [Error] no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, class

I can't compile my code because of some errors.

Here some of them :

In function 'int main(int, char**)':

```
[Error] no matching function for call to 'deckOfCards::shuffle(deckOfCards&)'

[Note] candidate is:

In file included from main.cpp

[Note] void deckOfCards::shuffle(std::vector<Card>&)

[Note] no known conversion for argument 1 from 'deckOfCards' to 'std::vector<Card>&'

[Error] 'dealCard' was not declared in this scope
```

---

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;


    class Card
    {
        private:
            int m_suit;
            int m_face;
        public:
            Card(int face, int suit);
            static string suits[];
            static string faces[];
            string toString(string s_face, string s_suit);
            int getFace();
            void setFace(int face);
            int getSuit();
            void setSuit(int suit);
    };

    Card::Card(int face, int suit)
    {
        m_face = face;
        m_suit = suit;
    } 

    string Card::suits[] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
    string Card::faces[] = {"Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", 
    "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    int Card::getFace(){return m_face;}
    void Card::setFace(int face){m_face = face;}
    int Card::getSuit(){return m_suit;}
    void Card::setSuit(int suit){m_suit = suit;}

    string Card::toString(string s_face, string s_suit)
    {
        string card = s_face + " of " + s_suit;
        return card;
    }





    #include <iostream>     // cout
#include <algorithm>    // random_shuffle
#include <vector>       // vector
#include <ctime>        // time
#include <cstdlib> 
#include "Card.h"

using namespace std;

class deckOfCards
{
    private:
        vector<Card> deck;

    public:
        deckOfCards();
        static int count;
        static int next;
        void shuffle(vector<Card>& deck);
        Card dealCard();
        bool moreCards();
};

int deckOfCards::count = 0;
int deckOfCards::next = 0;

deckOfCards::deckOfCards()
{
    const int FACES = 12;
    const int SUITS = 4;
    int currentCard = 0;
    for (int face = 0; face < FACES; face++)
        {
            for (int suit = 0; suit < SUITS; suit++)
                {
                    Card card = Card(face,suit); //card created and initialized
                    deck.push_back(card);
                    currentCard++;
                }
        }

}

void deckOfCards::shuffle(vector<Card>& deck)
{   
    random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());
    /*vector<Card>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = deck.begin(); iter!=deck.end(); iter++)
    {
        Card currentCard = *iter;
        random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());
        Card randomCard = deck[num];
        //change values.....
    }*/
}

Card deckOfCards::dealCard()
{
    Card nextCard = deck[next];
    next++;
    return nextCard;
}

bool deckOfCards::moreCards()
{
    if (count < 52)
    {
        count++;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}


    #include <iostream>
#include "deckOfCards.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    deckOfCards cardDeck; // create DeckOfCards object
    cardDeck.shuffle(cardDeck); // shuffle the cards in the deck
    while (cardDeck.moreCards() == true)
        {
            cout << dealCard(cardDeck);// deal the cards in the deck
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 74):

You are trying to call `DeckOfCards::shuffle` with a `deckOfCards` parameter:

```
deckOfCards cardDeck; // create DeckOfCards object
cardDeck.shuffle(cardDeck); // shuffle the cards in the deck
```

But the method takes a `vector<Card>&`:

```
void deckOfCards::shuffle(vector<Card>& deck)
```

---

The compiler error messages are quite clear on this.  I'll paraphrase the compiler as it talks to you.

Error:

```
[Error] no matching function for call to 'deckOfCards::shuffle(deckOfCards&)'
```

Paraphrased:

> Hey, pal.  You're trying to call a function called `shuffle` which
>   apparently takes a single parameter of type
>   reference-to-`deckOfCards`, but there is no such function.

Error:

```
[Note] candidate is:

In file included from main.cpp

[Note] void deckOfCards::shuffle(std::vector&)
```

Paraphrased:

> I mean, maybe you meant this other function called `shuffle`, but that
>   one takes a reference-to`vector<something>`.

Error:

```
[Note] no known conversion for argument 1 from 'deckOfCards' to 'std::vector&'
```

> Which I'd be happy to call if I knew how to convert from a
>   `deckOfCards` to a `vector`; but I don't.  So I won't.

Answer (score 7):

to add to John's answer:

what you want to pass to the `shuffle` function is a deck of cards from the class `deckOfCards` that you've declared in main; however, the deck of cards or `vector<Card> deck` that you've declared in your class is private, so not accessible from outside the class. this means you'd want a getter function, something like this:

```
class deckOfCards
{
    private:
        vector<Card> deck;

    public:
        deckOfCards();
        static int count;
        static int next;
        void shuffle(vector<Card>& deck);
        Card dealCard();
        bool moreCards();
        vector<Card>& getDeck() {   //GETTER
            return deck;
        }
};
```

this will in turn allow you to call your shuffle function from main like this:

```
deckOfCards cardDeck; // create DeckOfCards object
cardDeck.shuffle(cardDeck.getDeck()); // shuffle the cards in the deck
```

however, you have more problems, specifically when calling `cout`. first, you're calling the `dealCard` function wrongly; as `dealCard` is a memeber function of a class, you should be calling it like this `cardDeck.dealCard();` instead of this `dealCard(cardDeck);`.

now, we come to your second problem - print to standard output. you're trying to print your deal card, which is an object of type `Card` by using the following instruction:

```
cout << cardDeck.dealCard();// deal the cards in the deck
```

yet, the `cout` doesn't know how to print it, as it's not a standard type. this means you should [overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) your `<<` operator to print whatever you want it to print when calling with a `Card` type.